# Calling jQuery .toggle() on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, visible

I'm attempting to use jQuery to hide a livestream widget on [this page](http://curios-channel.tumblr.com/watch).

I've set the default visibility of the containing div to hide like so:

```
#library {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

Set up a button to toggle the state like so:

```
<a href="#" id="showhide">Show/Hide Reruns</a></span>
```

And tried to implement the function like this:

```
$('#showhide').click(function(e){
$('#library').toggle();
    return false;
    })
});
```

But I'm running into problems. The library widget is still visible on page load, and its CSS doesn't change in the element inspector either.

I've set up a fiddle here if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/GecwN/

Comment: can't you make a simpler fiddle ? i mean with no flash, and only the necessary elements

Comment: also use $.hide() instead of the css, it reduces headaches

Comment: I don't know that this is your issue, but your fiddle has an extra `})` at the end, and the click handler is outside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your toggle to this

```
    $('#showhide').click(function (e) {
        $('#library').toggleClass("library");
     })
```

I change the visibility property to

```
   display: none;
```

I also change your css from #library to .library in order to toggle the class

But then I think most importantly after doing those things, what I did was put your .click handler within the document.ready by just taking out the }) right before it. There was an extra one in there. It worked perfect

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/GecwN/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#library {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That would seem to solve my first problem, but I'm unsure if .toggle() works with display: none;

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have this in your `toggle()`:

```
return false;
```

Remove it and use `display: none` in your CSS as [TGH recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17667361/637369).

Sample [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cNmj5/).